# Calling C++ cocoa touch static library from iphone app

Tags: iphone, c++, cocoa-touch

I have developed a very simple C++ based cocoa touch static library and a simple  touch based application which includes this library.

The application gives compilation error "Undefined symbol" corresponding to the librarie's function being called.
ld: symbol(s) not found.

But if I make C based cocoa touch static library, (with same functionality), the application is successfully built and runs fine.

What can be the issue? Is C++ based cocoa touch library NOT ALLOWED ?

Thanks

Comment: You might want to set the file-type of the files that use your C++ lib to "cpp-opjcpp", and then clean and compile.

Comment: Sounds like a name-mangling issue - do as govi suggests or, as an alternative, rename your .cpp/.cc files to .mm and recompile.

Comment: The library has .cpp and .h source code, and test application had .m files. It was giving compilation error. To fix this , I just changed file extension of .m files to .mm in my test application. And it compiled, linked and ran successfully.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library has .cpp and .h source code, and test application had .m files. It was giving compilation error. To fix this , I just changed file extension of .m files to .mm in my test application. And it compiled, linked and ran successfully. Thanks